# Eth transaction on ethereum network

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs

I am trying to transfer eth from one address to another address using web3.js.
But I faced txHash undefined.

```
    var Tx = require("ethereumjs-tx").Transaction
    const Web3 = require('web3')
    const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/project_id')
    const account1 ='0x3df27f57A8...'
    const account2 = '0xa73e363e43...'
    const private_Key_1 = 'account1`s privateKey'
    const privateKey1Buffer = Buffer.from(private_Key_1, 'hex')

    await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (err,txCount) => {
        const txObject ={
            nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
            to: account2,
            value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.1', 'ether')),
            gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(21000),
            gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10','gwei')),
        }
        const tx = new Tx(txObject, { chain: 'mainnet' })
        tx.sign(privateKey1Buffer)

        const serializedTransaction =tx.serialize()
        const raw ='0x'+serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

        web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (err,txHash) => {
            console.log('txHash : ',txHash)                
        })
    })
```

I successed if network was ropsten.

```
    ...
    const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/project_id')
    ...
    cosnt tx = new Tx(txObject, { chain: 'ropsten' })
    ...
```

But I failed if network was mainnet.

Could you please anyone let me know about this issue?

So, finally I don`t know how can I set chain.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the failed transaction hash? what web3 version are you using? Check the gas price it varies a lot but it is almost always above 40gwei on mainnet.

Comment: I replaced gasPrice 100gwei and did successful tranasaction. Thanks! Ismael. How can I check available gasprice for this code? and could you please let me know differences between gasLimit and gasPrice?

Comment: You can use sites like ethgasstation.info or etherscan.io/gastracker.